# Is it possible to have frozen columns in slickgrid grouping(dataView.setGrouping()):

Tags: slickgrid

As per the sample image below, I need to make column frozen for 'title' column. Is it possible to implement the described scenario?

[image: Slickgrid grouping sample image]

Comment: NO, it's not currently possible to use these 2 features together, pinning uses 2 `<div>` container (left/right) and that has big side effect, you can't merge cell or do colspan because they are contained in their area (left or right container), it's a known issue and is well discussed in this [issue #443](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/443) on the `6pac/SlickGrid` fork. If anyone finds a solution that would be great, so please remember that this is an Open Source library and everyone can (should) contribute.

Comment: @ghiscoding, I'm able to implement the above changes but for the first time the width of the viewport Right/$container.width() is 0px so the grid is not visible. I have found that it only happening for the first time. Second time on rendering again it is taking the exact width from $container.width(). One more thing width is 0px only for non-frozen columns(first time only). Do you have any idea what is missing ?